# download failed : x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I just started learning Docker and Kubernetes. Installed minikube and docker on my windows machine. I am able to pull image from docker using docker pull command but getting below error with kubectl. Please help.

Warning Failed 18s (x2 over 53s) kubelet Failed to pull image "nginx:alpine": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority Warning Failed 18s (

This is my yml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: nginx1
spec:
containers:

name: nginx1
image: nginx:alpine
ports:
containerPort: 80
containerPort: 443
```

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfRTc.png)

Comment: Please refer official documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/ https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/ to configure docker daemon to pull images from repo

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml file looks messed up. Please ensure you write the yaml file properly. Can you test if this yaml file works for you? I have used a different image in the below mention yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx1
  namespace: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webserver
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "200m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "350m"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. still same error.

Failed to pull image "nginx:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=6: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: Now I need few inputs. Where is this machine ? is it behind some proxy ?